# Getting the country and/or city from an ip C#

Tags: c#, ip, subnet

I have been working on a code where I am inputting an ip, and the output is getting the host name and the location. The challenges I am having are for this code is they are ALL internal ip's and I am working with far too many subnets to create a list etc.

Is there a way to go about this using the System.Device.Location Namespace? I can get coordinates using geolocation but that isn't the goal out of this program. Being internal Ip's as well and API wouldn't work? I'll attach my code in what I have thus far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");
    IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
    Console.WriteLine("IP Address: " + addr);
    Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " + entry.HostName);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean internal IPs? Like `192.168.x.x` and `172.16.0.x`?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: So what location do you want? Internal IPs like that have no location as such, you'd need the external IP address.

Comment: WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                string publicIp = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
                Console.WriteLine("My public IP Address is: {0}", addr);

I have this using an api to get my public address, but in that way then I would need to figure a way out to use my addr variable in that code where if I input any ip.

Comment: Yes, that kind of IP. So it looks like you have the external IP from which you can get the hostname, so is it just the location you're missing?

Comment: I was playing around with it, trying to bring in the addr variable.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want my hostname, I want t be able to search any IP on my network and get the location.

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean. You can't get the location of a reserved IP, they're known only to your network and have no location. If you have the external IP then that's known to the rest of the internet and can be located. It sounds like you're trying to do something impossible.

Comment: Example, my server at home has an IP address of `192.168.0.200`. Can you tell me where in the world I'm located? No, because that address is known only to me on my network. The router uses NAT to connect that to my external IP which I'm not going to tell you ;-)

Comment: I'll try and get make sense of what I am getting at, can I input an ip, and get the external address, then from there use that api code I have?

Comment: Your problem is that you're querying Google's DNS records and asking about an internal IP address which it could not know about so this doesn't work. If you asked your own DNS server the same question it may be able to give you the external address for any given internal address, it depends on how it's set up.

Comment: It likely is set up the way you are describing. If there is no way to input and internal ip and get the external from that, than my next route would be trying something through dns

Comment: DNS is definitely the way to go. Out of interest, why do you need to do this? I don't understand the benefit of finding the external IP address of any given local machine.

Comment: For DNS, what route would I go with regarding it?

Comment: You'll probably need an extra library depending on your server, hard for me to help with. Some libraries are recommended in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227863/dns-lookup-from-custom-dns-server-in-c-sharp

Comment: I looked at that for all of a minute and I know that's the proper route, thank you!